# Django Queryset for most recent object with unique couple of values

Tags: python, django, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have a model structure similar to this:

```py
class DataFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('data.User', verbose_name='Data View')
    period = models.ForeignKey('data.Period', verbose_name='Period')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
```

I have a list of different tuples of users ids and periods ids, like
`{(272, 42), (78, 39), (280, 9), (73, 35), (81, 35), (62, 31), ...}`
and I need to retrieve the most recent model for each of these couples of values.
I couldn't come up with anything better than this:

```
data = []
my_data_list = DataFile.objects.all().values_list('user', "period").distinct()
for user, period in my_data_list:
    x = DataFile.objects.filter(user_id=user, period_id=period).order_by('created').last()
    data.append(x)
```

But is scaling very bad even for a little thousands elements in the database.

I am sure there is a more efficent way to retrieve this data, if you know one please provide it with some explanation

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: I'm using postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the `DataFile` records by filtering out `DataFile`s where there is a more recent record with an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries), so:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

DataFile.objects.filter(
    ~Exists(
        DataFile.objects.filter(
            user_id=OuterRef('user_id'),
            period_id=OuterRef('period_id'),
            created__gt=OuterRef('created'),
        )
    ),
)
```

For [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), you can however do this more effectively:

```
DataFile.objects.order_by('user', 'period', '-created').distinct('user', 'period')
```

this will thus only retrieve items with a distinct user and period, and since we ordered by `created` in descending order, we will get the most recent one.